A regular plane curve with no segment parameterisable as a line segment has a constant binormal? A clothoid?
This is an exercise in Valter Moretti's Analytical Mechanics

Exercises 2.21 (1) Consider the curve $\Gamma,$ of class $C^{1}$ and regular in $\mathbb{E}^{3},$
parametrised by its arclength $P=P\left(s\right),s\in\left(a,b\right)$.
Show that if $\Gamma$ is contained in a plane $\Pi$ and is not reparametrisable
as a line segment in any subinterval of $\left(a,b\right),$ then
the binormal $\mathbf{b}$ is constant along $\Gamma$ and perpendicular
to $\Pi.$

It seems to me that a clothoid fails to satisfy this condition.  One way of characterizing a clothoid is a curve whose curvature at a point is proportional to it its arc length at that point.  In order for a segment of the curve to be parameterized as a (straight) line segment, the curvature along the segment would have to be everywhere zero.  Moretti defines a segment in affine space as "obtained from a line by restricting $t$ to some
interval different from a point." $\mathbb{E}^3$ is a specialization of affine space. So there are no two points on a clothoid between which the curvature is everywhere zero.
Is this a valid counterexample to Moretti's assertion?
In fact, it would seem any S-shaped smooth curve would have a non-constant binormal.  I expect I am missing something.

A $C^2$ curve with nowhere-zero curvature has a Frenet frame at each point. If the curve is planar, its tangent and normal lie in the plane (technically, the subspace parallel to it) and the binormal is everywhere normal to the plane. Thus, assuming the curve is connected, the binormal is constant. However, if the curvature has even isolated zeroes, the curved  may indeed not have a continuous Frenet frame. So, if your clothoid switches convexity somewhere, then you are correct. The book’s hypotheses are not strong enough.

Dr Moretti, the author of the book agrees with my objection to the assertion in the exercise.  He also agrees with Ted Shifrin's comment.  I will clarify that the curve need not be S-shaped. In his Modern Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces with Mathematica, Third Edition  Alfred Gray defines the generalized clothoid as:
$$\text{clothoid}\left[n,a\right]\left(t\right) =a\left(\int_{0}^{t}\sin\left(\frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)du,\int_{0}^{t}\cos\left(\frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)du\right)$$
It is easily verified that for even clothoids, the binormal vector is the same everywhere it is defined.  It is, however, discontinuous at $t=0$ as it is for odd clothoids as well.

